# Can we use Rcpp with multiple C++ functions?

Tags: c++, c, r

I build my own function in `.c` language. Then, I buit an R function to call the `.c` function using `.C` e.g.,

```
 tmp <- .C("myfunction",
as.integer(N),
as.integer(n),
as.integer(w1),
as.integer(w2),
as.integer(w3),
PACKAGE = "mypackage")[[3]]
```

which is called a wraper R function. Also, my function based or requries other `.c` functions. As I know, using `Rcpp` make it is more flexiable and easy, such that:

```
cppFunction('int add(int x, int y, int z) {
  int sum = x + y + z;
  return sum;
}')
```

I also know that `cppFunction` works with `C++` language. However, I see there is no much different between `.c` function and `.c++`.

My question is: Can I use `cppFunction` with my `.c` function that requrie wraper R function? or I need to convert my `.c` functions into `.c++` functions first? What about other function that my function is based on? Does that will be as any regular `R` function?
 I mean: suppose I have two `cppFunction` functions `myfunc1` and `myfunc2` where `myfunc2` based on `myfunc1`. Then suppose my second `cppFunction` is as follows:

```
cppFunction('int myfunc2(int x, int y, int z) {
      int sum = x + y + z;
      myfunc1 ## do some works here
      return something;
    }')
```

Is that will be Ok? or Do I need to write it as follow:

```
cppFunction('int myfunc2(int x, int y, int z) {
      int sum = x + y + z;
      cppFunction('int myfunc2(int some arguments) {## do some works here}
      return something;
    }')
```

In general how to use build `cppFunction` that contains multiple functions?

any help please?

Comment: I think if you put everything in an Rcpp ".cpp" file (begin with the default of RStudio), it would be OK.

Comment: @F.Privé Many thanks for your comment. Do you mean that I  can do it as regular R functions including multiple functions?

Comment: I mean that if two Rcpp functions are in the same file, they know each other. Otherwise, you would have to use headers.

Comment: @F.Privé    Thank you again. Yes, I understand you know. I am using my own package and I think it will be ok as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example using an external cpp file.
The functions can interact inside the same file, but like others said you have to use header to use function from others files.
You have to use  `// [[Rcpp::export]]` before any functions you want available in R.

(Credit to @F.Privé for improving the code)

1)
File cpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;



// [[Rcpp::export]]
double sumC(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  double total = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    total += x[i];
  }
  return total;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double meanC(NumericVector x) {
  return sumC(x) / x.size();
}
```

File R:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("your path/mean.cpp")
x <- 1:10
meanC(x)
sumC(x)
```

2)***Alternative approach using cppfunction***. You have to use includes argument

```
cppFunction('double meanC(NumericVector x) {
  return sumC(x) / x.size();
}',includes='double sumC(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  double total = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    total += x[i];
  }
  return total;
}')
```

Anyway I suggest you to use sourceCpp, using independent files result in much more maintainable  and clean code

3)***Using sourceCPP and multiple cpp files***. You have to use headers file and do an header file for every file.cpp you want to use inside other cpp files.

sum.h file (ifndef prevent multiple definition)

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#ifndef SUM1
#define SUM1

double sumC(Rcpp::NumericVector x);

#endif
```

sum.cpp (like before)

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double sumC(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  double total = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    total += x[i];
  }
  return total;
}
```

mean.cpp file
 *(you have to include sum header)* #include "sum.h"

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "sum.h"
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double meanC(NumericVector x) {
  return sumC(x) / x.size();
}
```

Comment: Maybe to show Alice that functions know each other, you could use only `return sumC(x) / x.size();` in `meanC()`.

Comment: @F.Privé Yes your comment is really what I need.

Comment: @F.Privé Thank you so much and also many thanks to Federico Mangirasso for help. Then I can easy use `cppFunction`. Many thanks again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I adapt an example I had  for you and I was still editing. Please take notice, in order to use sumC inside meanC you have to define sumC before, otherwise the code does not compile

Comment: @FedericoManigrasso could you please add using `cppFunction` to your answer since it is the main part of my question so it will be very helpful for who may interest. Many thanks,.

Comment: @FedericoManigrasso your answer is great.

Comment: @FedericoManigrasso I tried to use your example (worked very well) in a separate `cppFunction` functions but I get an error. You mentioned that in your comment. That I need to define sumC before using meanC. But I get error and I do not know how to do so. could you please help me to figure it out.

Comment: @FedericoManigrasso I built two `cppFunction` functions one for `SumC` and another for `meanC` and saved them in one file. Then source the file but it gave me an error saying that `SumC` is not define. Your answer worked very well but I tried to separate the functions to make it more easy to maintane the code (as you suggested with `sourceCpp`)