# Compilation steps for a c++ file with Rcpp header file

Tags: c++, rcpp

I am trying this code on gedit and compiling by g++ compiler on terminal.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double sumC(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  double total = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    total += x[i];
  }
  return total;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double meanC(NumericVector x) {
  return sumC(x) / x.size();
}
```

Error occurred for the header file.

> fatal error: Rcpp.h: No such file or directory

I have compiled like this: **g++  -I /usr/  r1.cpp -o c0 -L /usr/ -lRcpp** 
Also i tried :**g++  -I /usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/ r1.cpp -o c0 -L /usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/libs/ -lRcpp** . THen got error like fatal

> `error: R.h: No such file or directory  #include <R.h>`

```
Locations:
 locate Rcpp.h:/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h
 locate R.h:/usr/share/R/include/R.h
```

I have tried with make file also. 
My make file:

```
all:
    g++ rcpp.cpp -o obj
compile:
```

I have attached all the depending header files in a single folder. Still getting the errors for Rcpp.

Any one knows how to compile this through terminal?

Comment: Are you trying to compile this C++ file into a program you can run? That won’t work without a `main()`. Besides that [yesterday’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51058558/8416610) still applies.

Comment: :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45296381/can-we-use-rcpp-with-multiple-c-functions .

Comment: In that question helper function from Rcpp are used to compile and link the above C++ file and load it into a running R process. What is the expected result of all this?

Comment: I fear you continue to misunderstand _how_ this works and _how_ this is supposed to be used.  From R, in both case.  Maybe try looking at the updated [Rcpp Introduction](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

You can compile this file with

```
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include -c rcpp.cpp -o rcpp.o
```

However, I do not understand why you want to do this. In order to make such C++ functions callable from R, several additional steps are necessary:

- C++ wrapper functions that translate to an interface based on R's `SEXP`.
- R wrapper functions that call the C++ wrapper functions via `.Call()`.
- Linking of all the object files into a dynamic library that R can load.
- Loading the library and the R wrapper functions into R.

All this is automated via `sourceCpp()` or when using `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` in the context of packages using Rcpp, c.f. the vignettes on [attributes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) and [packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf).

Comment: I am new to this area and first time trying to call a R function from Cpp.

Comment: _g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include -c rcpp.cpp -o rcpp.o_ this creates a  rcpp.o file. This file is object file between compiling and linking. its not executable with ./rcpp.o

Comment: @Aswathy Yes, that is the result of the command. Is that a statement or a  (hidden) question?

Comment: :its working and creates a object file . But need to create the -L also for linking. I think then only i can convert the object file to executable one.

Comment: @9113303 If you want an executable that you can call directly, then you will have to do a bit more. RInside helps with that. We can also help you once you explain what you are trying to do. See [ask].