# How to call a function from another function in Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I defined two functions in c++ which I am calling in R using Rcpp package. I put both f1 and f2 functions inside one cppFunction(). After running this, the f1 function works correctly in R, but I get this error while calling f2:"could not find function f2". Here is the code:

```
cppFunction('
std::vector<double> f1( double lambda, double gamma) {
double a = exp(-(lambda+gamma));
double b = lambda+gamma;
std::vector<double> v;
v.push_back(a);
v.push_back(b);
return v;
}
std::vector<double> f2(double lambda, double gamma ,double alpha) {
std::vector<double> res;
res=f1(lambda, gamma);
res[0] *= alpha;
res[1] *= 1-alpha;
double lik = res[0]+res[1];
res.push_back(lik);
res.push_back(res[1]);
return res;
}
')
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: First thing to do would be to check the rcpp documentation to make sure you can define 2 functions in one `cppFunction` block.

Comment: You are (just as the previous comment suggests) constrained by `cppFunction()`. Use `sourceCpp()` or write a package.

Comment: You can actually do it with `cppFunction()` (and its predecessor from the `inline` package) but you need to suppy a list of chunks as each chunk gets wrapped behind the scenes. `sourceCpp()` is easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `includes` in `cppFunction`:

```
cppFunction('
std::vector<double> f2(double lambda, double gamma ,double alpha) {
  std::vector<double> res;
  res=f1(lambda, gamma);
  res[0] *= alpha;
  res[1] *= 1-alpha;
  double lik = res[0]+res[1];
  res.push_back(lik);
  res.push_back(res[1]);
  return res;
}
', includes = {'std::vector<double> f1( double lambda, double gamma) {
  double a = exp(-(lambda+gamma));
  double b = lambda+gamma;
  std::vector<double> v;
  v.push_back(a);
  v.push_back(b);
  return v;
};
'})
```

*Credit: Thanks to [Federico Manigrasso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7600734/federico-manigrasso) of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45296773/16077905)!*